# Representing a class table in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I would like to represent a kind of class table (CT) as a singleton in Rascal, so that some transformations might refer to the same CT. Since not all transformations need to refer to the CT (and I prefer not to change the signature of the existing transformations), I was wondering if it is possible to implement a kind of *singleton object* in Rascal.

Is there any recommendation for representing this kind of situation?

Edited: found a solution, though still not sure if this is the idiomatic Rascal approach.

```
module lang::java::analysis::ClassTable

import Map;

import lang::java::m3::M3Util;

// the class table considered in the source 
// code analysis and transformations. 
map[str, str] classTable = ();


/**
 * Load a class table from a list of JAR files. 
 * It uses a simple cache mechanism to avoid loading the 
 * class table each time it is necessary. 
 */ 
 map[str, str] loadClassTable(list[loc] jars) {
   if(size(classTable) == 0) {
     classTable = classesHierarchy(jars);
   }
   return classTable;
 }
```

Comment: The term "singleton object" as a term has no related concept in Rascal. The reason is that we don't have data objects, just immutable values. So there is no way to distinguish data instances from each other. A singleton in OO is an object which occurs only once in memory, but in Rascal there exists no language to decribe such behavior. If two data values look the same, then they are the same from the Rascal programmer's standpoint. Maybe there are two in memory... maybe they are shared. The only way to have a kind of observerable "state" in Rascal is via the concept of "variables" in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two answers to the question: "what to do if you want to share data acros functions and modules, but not pass the data around as an additional parameter, or as an additional return value?":

- a public global variable can hold a reference to a shared data-object like so: `public int myGlobalInt = 666;` This works for all kinds of (complex) data, including class tables. Use this only if you need shared *state* of the public variable.
- a `@memo` function is a way to provide fast access to shared data in case you need to share data which will not be modified (i.e. you do not need shared state): `@memo int mySharedDataProvider(MyType myArgs) = hardToGetData();`. The function's behavior must not have side-effects, i.e. be "functional", and then it will never recompute the return value for earlier provided arguments (instead it will use an internal table to cache previous results).